# Why doesn't my Microsoft Outlook 2007 get emails automatically in the background?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

In Outlook, when I am click on send/receive button at that time I am able to receive email.

But when my Outlook is running in the background I am not able to receive email, and the send/receive process of Outlook continues, but doesn't complete all tasks going on in the send/receive process.

I also set automatically (notification of new mail) send/receive process in background.

Answer (score 1):

In Outlook 2010 (though I'm not sure but it should be similar in Outlook 2007)

(1) click send/receive tab -> click send/receive groups -> all accounts group -> on a new send/receive groups window -> select the schedule an automatic send/receive every *n* (a number between 1 and 1440) minutes check box.

(2) If you want, you can specify a schedule for send/receive when Outlook is offline. Under When Outlook is offline, select the schedule an automatic send/receive every *n* minutes check box.

[image]

[image]

you can find more info at this [Outlook Help and How-to page](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/schedule-when-a-send-receive-command-runs-HA010117941.aspx)